# Uniqie Discord.js bot per user on localhost

Tags: discord.js, localhost, multiple-instances

I've created a discord bot that runs locally on user's machines and I'm not exactly sure how it would work if for example 30 people are running their local instances at the same time. Will other users's instances emit events to eachother or is each running instance only going to care about its own script.

Comment: Is each one running a different bot account? Or all the same account?

Comment: All running the same account

Comment: As far as I know, every instance would get the same events. There generally shouldn't be conflicts. That being said, I'm not sure how much Discord really supports that. If you want the bot to run in multiple guilds, you should write the code to support that—giving the bot account to 30 other people is unsafe since they could do anything in any server that it has permission to do. This includes deleting every single channel and message in those servers, and banning everyone.